# WPF Tab Control Headers on the left side

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I want to make my custom tab control style. Headers should be on the left side and the content on the right side. Just like the standard styles can do it:[image]

The selected element on the image above is the grid inside the active item. As you can see, it perfectly aligns next to the headers.

[image]

This is my design. The selected element is also the grid inside the active item, but it is just behind the headers instead of next to them. How can I align this grid next to the headers?

These are my styles for the tab item and tab control:

```
 <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TabPanel
                        Name="HeaderPanel"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                        Margin="0" 
                        IsItemsHost="True"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                        Background="AliceBlue" />
                    <Border 
                            Name="Border" 
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" >
                        <ContentPresenter 
                              Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                              Margin="4"
                              ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Margin="0"
                        Padding="10,4,4,4"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Height="30"                               
                        Width="Auto"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"                                   
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            ContentSource="Header"                                   
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4576a9"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="6, 0, 0, 0"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="4"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Custom Template, you need to set `Grid.Column` instead of `Grid.Row` since your grid is now 2 cols/1 row instead of 1 col/2 rows

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Grid ...>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabPanel
            Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" ... />
        <Border Name="Border" Grid.Column="1" ... >
            <ContentPresenter ... />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need not to create a custom control. You can use TabStripPlacement property of tabcontrol to achieve this functionality.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">

            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2">

            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

You can refer http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/tabcontrol/tab-positions/ or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.tabstripplacement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: TabStripPlacement has no influence on my custom style.

Comment: TabStripPlacement = Left will give the desired result that you are looking. You want to place content on the side of the header right

Comment: This works if you don't make a custom template. If you make your own template, you have to do it like @Rachel described in her answer.